# Openshift domain shows instead of desired domain

Tags: openshift, nameservers

I have the domain `test.com`(just as an example), which I have bought from namecheap. I have redirected the domain to `http://app-test.rhcloud.com/`. However, when entering `test.com` in my browser I still can see `http://app-test.rhcloud.com/` in the browser instead of `test.com`. Any recommendation how to clean that up?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cname for your application, not a redirect.  A redirect just tells the browser, now go to this domain instead.  Check out this blog article for the correct way to setup what you are trying to do: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way